# Mongoose Schema with both fields and any

Tags: mongoose

I want something like this:

```
var TheSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  field1: { type: String, required: true },
  field2: Boolean,
});
```

And these data as valid data:

```
{
  field1: "FIELD 1"
}
```

and

```
{
  field1: "FIELD 1",
  field3: "FIELD 3"
}
```

And this data as an invalid data:

```
{
  field2: true,
  field3: "FIELD 3"
}
```

For those who the above mentioned situation doesn't make sense I should add I want to declare just two fields and let a model to has extra fields but should validate the declared fields (As I know the option `strict: false` makes the schema to not validate model at all. If I'm wrong correct me please!)

Comment: It's not `restrict: false` but is `strict: false`

Comment: Yes, My bad! Thanks @ZeMoon